# Unable to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 8

Tags: installation

I already have windows 8 installed in c drive of my laptop, am trying to install Ubuntu in D or E drive, it is showing as unable to mount those drives, how to install Ubuntu into D or E drive with out deleting or formatting windows8. please help me thank you.

My laptop details:
HP pavilion G6.

Should i do any settings in boot-manager?

Comment: Since you seem to know very little about Linux, I would recommend you try it out in VirtualBox or something similar first, if you don't know what you're doing you're bound to mess up your partitions and come back with an unusuable system. Dual booting is not for learning Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give some no formated free space to ubuntu installation. after installing you can use your drives D and E by mounting them.

In general, the concept of Partitions and Drives in linux are different from in windows.
All the files are organized like a tree around the root(spelled the directory /) directory which has been chosen at the time of installation.

in linux you can have your data s in windows partitions format(FAT,NTFS), But <del>sorrily</del>unfortunately, Windows does not support Linux formats.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Ubuntu iso , prepare a live usb, its fairly easy. Find how to do it, yourselves.

Go to windows 8, press winkey + R type diskmgmt.msc,press enter.

1. Delete the D drive , so that it shows up as unallocated space. make sure you apply the changes.
2. Now restart the computer go into bios, usually it is done by pressing f2 or f10.. find the boot sequence and set the usb on top.(in short boot from the damn usb)

   NOTE:An yeah don't forget to change it again to the hard drive when installation is complete.
3. A "window"or screen will open,press enter on the option that says try without installing.

After booting in Ubuntu , press the window key and type gparted, open it up.

Don't worry about the confusion of sda1 and all. If you aren't sure then refrain from doing anything,without seeking help.

Now Press on the unallocated space,and change...set the ENTIRE SPACE AS EXTENDED PARTITION.

After doing it you will still have unallocated space from that space do the following

All of them are LOGICAL PARTITION.

1. set the size as around 30Gb(approx 30,000), choose type as ext4 , mount point as / . this is where Ubuntu will be installed.
2. again press on the remaining unallocated space, set the size around 2gb(approx 2000) , choose type as swap.
3. press on the unallocated space, change size to the maximum, this is where you will be storing your FILES/DATA. choose type as ext4 and mount point as /home.

Apply the changes and close gparted. If you aren't sure what you have done then , post a screenshot of gparted after doing all this.

If you have come this far , then go to the desktop press on install Ubuntu icon ,when the option comes choose SOMETHING ELSE and choose the drive which has the partitions you just made above and bingo! Proceed to install. Good Luck.

Comment: Haha grammar nazi. Sorry I will try saying Ubuntu instead of ubuntu. I am a total noob too. I learnt all this from a user named "fantab" on ubuntuforums.org and I have been successfully able to dual boot , still you shouldn't be doing it without backing up all your data.